# How to use PlistBuddy using command substiution

Tags: bash, shell, plistbuddy

I am trying the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT="$(cat /Users/admin/Desktop/plist-script-output/keys-updated.txt | sed 's/"//g; s/^/-c "Print :/g; s/$/"/g' | tr '\n' ' ')"

FILE="/Users/admin/Desktop/plist-script-output/plist-data/data.plist"

PLISTBUDDY=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy $OUTPUT $FILE 2>&1)
echo "$PLISTBUDDY"
```

The output of the above script is **Unrecognized Command**

The value of OUTPUT variable is

-c "Print :Ant-Conversion" -c "Print :Newitem" -c "Print :Area" -c "Print :Contact"

**2>&1** this is added so as to print both the errors (does not exist keys) and proper output.

The **keys-updated.txt** contains the list of keys to be extracted from the plist files (not necessary all are present in the plist)

### SOLUTION (NOT WORKING)

Tried the solution from @Nahuel. however the line

**PLISTBUDDY=$(eval set -- $OUTPUT;/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$@" "$FILE")**

provides only the **list of keys which do not exist in the plist**

This is the output I am receiving after using the solution from @Nahuel

Print: Entry, "Status", Does Not Exist

Print: Entry, "Notify", Does Not Exist

Print: Entry, "IsMvnMgrSupported", Does Not Exist

Print: Entry, "BuildsetFile", Does Not Exist

Print: Entry, "RollupClocReportToModule", Does Not Exist

Print: Entry, "Branches", Does Not Exist

Print: Entry, "Ant-Conversion", Does Not Exist

Print: Entry, "IndexTag", Does Not Exist

Print: Entry, "WO", Does Not Exist

Print: Entry, "Tags", Does Not Exist

Print: Entry, "Newitem", Does Not Exist

ON USING THE COMMAND DIRECTLY ON COMMAND LINE

**admin:Desktop admin$** . 
**/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :Area" -c "Print :Contact" -c "Print :Email" -c "Print :Language" -c "Print :Location" -c "Print :Name" -c "Print :Notes" -c "Print :Purpose" -c "Print :Track" -c "Print :Type" -c "Print :URL" -c "Print :Status" -c "Print :Notify" -c "Print :IsMvnMgrSupported" -c "Print :BuildsetFile" -c "Print :RollupClocReportToModule" -c "Print :Branches" -c "Print :Ant-Conversion" -c "Print :IndexTag" -c "Print :WO" -c "Print :Tags" -c "Print :Newitem" /Users/admin/Desktop/plist-script-output/plist-data/ActiveMQ.plist**

The output turns out to be

**Monitoring . 
cucducheuneun . 
cdcdcdcdc . 
Java . 
dvfvfvfvfvfvfv . 
ActiveMQ . 
cddcdcdcdc . 
An messaging (JMS) framework from the Apache Software Foundation.

Infrastructure . 
Framework . 
jdbcjdbcdjdcnnjn . 
Print: Entry, ":Status", Does Not Exist . 
Print: Entry, ":Notify", Does Not Exist . 
Print: Entry, ":IsMvnMgrSupported", Does Not Exist . 
Print: Entry, ":BuildsetFile", Does Not Exist . 
Print: Entry, ":RollupClocReportToModule", Does Not Exist . 
Print: Entry, ":Branches", Does Not Exist . 
Print: Entry, ":Ant-Conversion", Does Not Exist . 
Print: Entry, ":IndexTag", Does Not Exist . 
Print: Entry, ":WO", Does Not Exist . 
Print: Entry, ":Tags", Does Not Exist . 
Print: Entry, ":Newitem", Does Not Exist . 
Abort trap: 6**

Answer (score 0):

After looking at sed, and tr commands. Seems /Users/admin/Desktop/plist-script-output/keys-updated.txt contains

```
Ant-Conversion
Newitem
Area
Contact
```

the whole can be done with bash builtins :

```
# local args arr pcmd (if inside a function)
# readarray -t arr </Users/admin/Desktop/plist-script-output/keys-updated.txt
# because readarray doesn't work on Mac
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' arr </Users/admin/Desktop/plist-script-output/keys-updated.txt

args=()
for pcmd in "${arr[@]}"; do
    args+=(-c "Print :$pcmd")
done

PLISTBUDDY=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "${args[@]}" "$FILE" 2>&1)
```

---

First answer:

```
OUTPUT='-c "Print :Ant-Conversion" -c "Print :Newitem" -c "Print :Area" -c "Print :Contact"'
```

The quotes are not syntactical because quote processing is done before variable expansion.

Not safe (injection), int this case using eval

```
PLISTBUDDY=$(eval /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy $OUTPUT $FILE 2>&1)
```

Can't think to something better for the moment

Slightly better

```
PLISTBUDDY=$(eval set -- $OUTPUT;/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$@" "$FILE" 2>&1)
```

Comment: Thanks Nahuel Fouilleul for providing the solution. However **PLISTBUDDY=$(eval set -- $OUTPUT;/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$@" "$FILE" 2>&1)**   is printing only those keys which are not present in the plist file. I want the output to contain result for all the keys rather than just those keys which are not present in the plist

Comment: As per the above solution I am not receiving the output for those keys which are present in the plist. The output contains only the list of "does not exist" keys. Can you please help @Nahuel Fouilleul

Comment: This time my OUTPUT variable contains the following

Comment: readarray not working on MacOSX.... thanks fr the solution though.. can you provide any other snippet which could work on Mac

Comment: The answer resolve issue with bash, the other issues are from PlistBuddy

Comment: /Users/admin/Desktop/plist-script-output/plist-data/try.sh: line 4: local: can only be used in a function
/Users/admin/Desktop/plist-script-output/plist-data/try.sh: line 5: readarray: command not found.......These are the errors i am receiving on using the new solution

Comment: Getting **Unrecognized Command** for the latest solution provided @NahuelFouilleul

Comment: In the updated answer I tried printing $pcmd inside the for loop ....the output seems to be wrong Print
:Area
Contact
Email

Comment: output of the array after the for loop is -c Print -c :Area -c Contact -c Email -c Language -c Location -c Name -c Notes -c Purpose -c Track -c Type -c URL -c Status -c Notify -c IsMvnMgrSupported -c BuildsetFile -c RollupClocReportToModule -c Branches -c Ant-Conversion -c IndexTag -c WO -c Tags -c Newitem

Comment: However the output should be -c "Print :Area" -c "Print :Email" . .....